# Where is it implied that REST is not based on HTTP

Tags: rest, http

I've been over Fielding's paper on REST and all over the web, including StackOverflow trying to understand this.

After reading everything I can about REST, I was under the impression that Fielding based REST on top of HTTP, using it as a stepping stone. But then I go and read some people saying that REST  actually doesn't depend on HTTP and it could be implemented perfectly over FTP (to give an example).

Is there any official paper (mainly from Fielding) specifically explaining this?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you've read at least [chapter 5](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) and [chapter 6](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm) of [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)?

Comment: We don't generally handle search requests here. That's what Google is for.  In the meantime, you might find [this](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284) interesting.

Comment: @MichaelT yes I have read those.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for that, I'm not asking for a google search, I'm asking for someone who's read something out there that says "REST is protocol independet" or the opposite and can explain it to me.

Comment: I wonder if you're just seeing minor variations in emphasis and being misled? To me it seems that this might be better explained in terms of network layering rather than software architecture per se. REST is a higher layer than HTML, and both sit on top of the 9-ish layer network stack. Each layer is largely independent of the layers below it, and some (most) layers can run on multiple different implementations of lower layers (ethernet vs 2/3/4G, for example). In your case REST can run on HTTP or FTP or SSH or whatever.

Comment: What's the difference between finding it on a search or having someone else tell you they read it? Other than it's much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This answer is based on excerpts from [Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)**, Roy T. Fielding's PhD

The **[Introduction](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/introduction.htm)** to Fielding's dissertation reads, in part:

> Over the past six years, the REST architectural style has been used to guide the design and development of the architecture for the modern Web

**[Chapter 5](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) Section 5.3.2**  reads, in part:

> REST does not restrict communication to a particular protocol, but it
> does constrain the interface between components, and hence the scope
> of interaction and implementation assumptions that might otherwise be
> made between components.
>
> For example, the Web's primary transfer
> protocol is HTTP, but the architecture also includes seamless access
> to resources that originate on pre-existing network servers, including
> FTP, Gopher, and WAIS. Interaction with those services
> is restricted to the semantics of a REST connector.
>
> This constraint
> sacrifices some of the advantages of other architectures, such as the
> stateful interaction of a relevance feedback protocol like WAIS, in
> order to retain the advantages of a single, generic interface for
> connector semantics. In return, the generic interface makes it
> possible to access a multitude of services through a single proxy.  If
> an application needs the additional capabilities of another
> architecture, it can implement and invoke those capabilities as a
> separate system running in parallel, similar to how the Web
> architecture interfaces with "telnet" and "mailto" resources.

Further more in **[Chapter 6](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm)** Fielding goes on to give examples of how REST was the drive behind URI ([5](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/references.htm#ref_21)) and HTTP ([6](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/references.htm#ref_19), [7](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/references.htm#ref_42))

From this we can see that Fielding's contributions to Web standards (including HTTP) was driven by the defining principles, or constraints of the REST architectural style.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a good quote recently (can't find the link now) that flipped the equation around: that HTTP is a RESTful protocol. In other words, if you want to implement a RESTful service, leveraging HTTP is a good bet because it embodies the principles of REST.

So rather than saying that REST is built on HTTP -- which is how I always thought of it -- it's better to say that REST is a set of design principles which are realized in the HTTP protocol. HTTP is a RESTful protocol.

(Now it may actually have played out that REST emerged from observing what worked well with HTTP, but for argument's sake we can pretend that REST encompasses a certain set of eternal principles and HTTP just happened to take form around them. ;) )